# Oracle Apex SQL Pie Chart Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am trying to make a SQL statement for a pie chart

I need the pie chart to link to a table called 'students' within this table I have a column called APPLICANT_ACCEPTED which contains the value 'Y' or 'N' I need the pie chart to display all of the 'Y' values and 'N' values.

Anyone able to help?

Thanks

Comment: Here is my attempt    SELECT null link,
'Placed' label,
count APPLICANT_APPROVED
FROM "STUDENTS"
WHERE status = 'Y'

Answer (score 0):

Example query with arbitrary dataset. Please do the effort of providing more information and info on what you have done or tried in the future. A little search effort would go a long way!

```
WITH dataset AS (
  SELECT 'a' applicant_name, 'N' applicant_accepted FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b', 'Y' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c', 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd', 'Y' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'e', 'N' FROM dual
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 'f', 'N' FROM dual
)
SELECT NULL link, 'Accepted' label, count(case applicant_accepted when 'Y' then 1 end) value
  FROM dataset
UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'Rejected', count(case applicant_accepted when 'N' then 1 end)
  FROM dataset
```